# Download file from JSP with Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, mysql

The context: I have a JSP presenting an HTML page. Here I can choose files from a table (populated via MySQL). clicking on a row: the file is loaded from the DB (via MySQL query), then built via stream, then it should be downloaded. I'm able to build a file from a stream, but I can't enable the correct procedure for download it. The software is running on local, so there's no a client/server architecture (I'm aware Javascript is problematicfor this)  I read many questions here about using Javascript, href links, jquery, but nothing seems to work. 
Can someone provide a "classic example" or proper implementation for this? Sorry if my description is a little vague, I'll provide further details if necessary. Have a look to my jsp (Please ignore the code parts not related). Note: Some errors are due to uncoplete deleting of my efforts

> ```
> `<%@ page import="org.jdom2.Element"%>
> <%@ page
>   import="org.yawlfoundation.yawl.resourcing.rsInterface.WorkQueueGatewayClient"%>
> <%@ page import="org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter"%>
> <%@ page import="org.jdom2.output.Format"%>
> <%@ page import="org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder"%>
> <%@ page import="java.io.StringReader"%>
> <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
> <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
> <%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
> <%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
> <%@ page import="org.jdom2.Element"%>
> <%@ page import="org.yawlfoundation.yawl.elements.data.YParameter"%>
> <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
> <%@ page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
>
> <%
>   String username = "";
>   String password = "password";
>   String columns = "columns";
>   String data1 = "<tr>";
>   String taskFlag = "void";
>   String clickedDOC = "";
>   String link = "";
>   String jDocTitle = "dummy jDocTitle";
>
>   String varName = "username";
>   String varName2 = "addDocument";
>   String varName3 = "addRequest";
>   String varName4 = "evaluateRequest";
>   String varName5 = "removeDocument";
>   String varName6 = "removeRequest";
>   String varName7 = "exit";
>
>   String wqURL = "http://localhost:8080/resourceService/workqueuegateway";
>   String error = "error";
>
>   boolean isModified = false;
>   boolean addDocument = false;
>
>
>   String redirectURL = (String) session.getAttribute("redirectURL");
>   if (redirectURL == null) {
>       redirectURL = request.getParameter("source");
>       session.setAttribute("redirectURL", redirectURL);
>   }
>
>   String submit = request.getParameter("submit");
>   System.out.println("submit: " + submit);
>
>   WorkQueueGatewayClient wqClient = new WorkQueueGatewayClient(wqURL);
>   String itemXML = (String) session.getAttribute("itemXML");
>
>   //if (itemXML == null) {
>
>       String itemid = request.getParameter("workitem");
>       String handle = request.getParameter("handle");
>
>       itemXML = wqClient.getWorkItem(itemid, handle);
>       session.setAttribute("itemXML", itemXML);
>       session.setAttribute("workitem", itemid);
>       session.setAttribute("handle", handle);
>   //}
>
>   if ((submit != null) && submit.equals("Add Document")) { // VALUTARE SE IL TASK TERMINA E VA RIAVVIATO (A TERMINE ADD) O SE RIMANE
> ```
>
> ATTIVO (E DISPONIBILE DOPO ADD)
>             System.out.println("AddDocument clicked");
>
> ```
>       taskFlag = "addDocument";
>       addDocument = true;
>       isModified = true;
>       System.out.println("isModified: " + isModified);
>        /*  session.removeAttribute("itemXML");
>       session.removeAttribute("workitem");
>       session.removeAttribute("handle");
>       session.removeAttribute("redirectURL");   */
>        redirectURL += "?complete=true";
>       response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL(redirectURL)); 
>       return; 
>
>   }
>
>   Element wir = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(itemXML)).getRootElement();
>   Element updatedData = wir.getChild("updateddata");
>   Element data = (updatedData.getContentSize() > 0) ? updatedData : wir.getChild("data");
>   Element wirData = data.getChildren().get(0);
>
>   System.out.println("itemXML: " + itemXML);
>
>   if (!wqClient.successful(itemXML)) {
>
>       error = itemXML;
>       System.out.println("incipit error itemXML: " + itemXML);
>   } else { // wqClient.successful(itemXML)
>
>       if (wir != null) { //NIENTE DA INSERIRE NELL' IF
>           if (wirData != null) {
>
>               Element usernameXML = wirData.getChild(varName);
>               //Element taskFlagXML = wirData.getChild("taskFlag");
>               Element addDocumentXML =  wirData.getChild("addDocument");
>               //addDocumentXML.removeContent();
>               // System.out.println("addDocumentXML: " + addDocumentXML.getText());
>               /*Element addRequestXML = null;
>               Element evaluateRequestXML = null;
>               Element removeDocumentXML = null;
>               Element removeRequestXML = null;
>               Element exitXML = null; */
>
>               if (usernameXML != null) {
>
>                   username = usernameXML.getText();
>                   //addDocument.removeContent();
>                   //taskFlagXML.setText(taskFlag);
>                   addDocumentXML.setText("true");
>
>                    itemid = (String) session.getAttribute("workitem");
>                    handle = (String) session.getAttribute("handle");
>                   String dataString = new XMLOutputter(Format.getCompactFormat()).outputString(wirData);
>
>                   String result = wqClient.updateWorkItemData(itemid, dataString, handle);
>                   System.out.println("itemXML2: " + itemXML);
>
>                   if (wqClient.successful(result) && isModified) { // QUI OPZIONE COMPLETAMENTO VALIDO
>
>                       System.out.println("isModified 3: " + isModified);
>                       /*  session.removeAttribute("itemXML");
>                       session.removeAttribute("workitem");
>                       session.removeAttribute("handle");
>                       session.removeAttribute("redirectURL"); */
>
>                       redirectURL += "?complete=true";
>                       response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL(redirectURL));
>
>                   } else { // wqClient.successful(result))
>                       error = result;
>                       System.out.println("not wqClient.successful(result): " + error);
>                   }
>               } else { //dataitem != null && dataitem2 != null
>
>                   error = "dataitems null";
>                   System.out.println(error);
>                   System.out.println("itemXML: " + itemXML);
>                   System.out.println("inputs: " + username + " , " + password);
>                   System.out.println("wirdata: " + wirData);
>               }
>
>           } else {//wirData
>               error = "This workitem does not contain any data for updating.";
>               System.out.println(error);
>           }
>       } else {
>           System.out.println("inputs null: ");
>       }
>   }
>
>   System.out.println("SQL start");
>
>   String queryAllDocuments = "SELECT title, file FROM appuser, document WHERE appuser.username = '" + username
>           + "' AND appuser.role = document.applicantRole";
>   String queryAllRequests = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE request.applicantUsername = '" + username +"'";
>   String queryPendingRequests = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE request.applicantUsername = '" + username
>           + "' AND request.status = 'pending' ";
>   String queryAllEvaluatingRequests = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE request.evaluetorUsername = '" + username+"'";
>   String queryEvaluatingPendingRequests = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE request.evaluetorUsername = '"
>           + username + "' AND request.status = 'pending' ";
>   String queryGetDoc = "SELECT file FROM document WHERE document.title =";
>
>   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>   Connection connection1 = DriverManager
>           .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
> ```
>
> "root", "root");
>         Statement statement1 = connection1.createStatement();
>
> ```
>    ResultSet resultSet1; 
>    resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery(queryAllDocuments);
>    System.out.println("resultSet1: "+resultSet1.first());
>    ResultSet resultSet2;
>    Statement statement2 = connection1.createStatement();
>    ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
>    rsmd = resultSet1.getMetaData();
>    System.out.println("rsmd: "+rsmd.getColumnCount());
>   int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
>   int index = 1;
>   int titleIndex = 1; // unica colonna doc
>
>   boolean flag = false;
>   while(flag){
>    jDocTitle = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("docTitle"));  // click su docTitle
>
>   if(jDocTitle.equals(null) ){
>       System.out.println("jDocTitle: "+jDocTitle);
>   queryGetDoc+= "'"+jDocTitle+"'";
> resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery(queryGetDoc);
> System.out.println("resultSet2: "+resultSet2.first());
>   if(resultSet2!=null || !resultSet2.first()){
>   //resultSet2.first();
>   //costruisci file da query
>        System.out.println("jDocTitle1: "+jDocTitle);
>   File file = new File(jDocTitle);
>   file.createNewFile();
>   FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
>   InputStream  is = resultSet2.getBinaryStream(1);
>
>   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
>   int len;
>
>    for (int i = is.read(); i != -1; i = is.read()) {
>        fop.write(i);
>      }
>
>    is.close();
>    fop.close();
>
>   }
>   }else{
>       jDocTitle = "dummy docTitle"; 
>       System.out.println("docTitle null");
>   }
>
>    flag = false;
>   }
>   // <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> %>
>
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
>
>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html>
>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <title>Insert title here</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function downloadFunction(){
>   var doc = document.getElementById("availableDocument").value;
>   doc = window.location= file;
>   alert(doc);
>   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
>   if(!doc){
>       doc = "no doc clicked";
>   }else
>       {
>
>
>   document.getElementById(doc).innerHTML = this.responseText;
>
>    xhttp.send();
>       }
>    flag = true;
>
> }
> </script>
>   <form name="userDataForm" method="post" action="" >
>       <h1>Welcome User</h1>
>       <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
>       <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
>       <h3>Available Documents</h3>
>       <table id= "docTable" style="height: 21px; float: left;" width="380">
>           <tbody>
>           <tr>
>               <%
>               for (int i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
>                   System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
>                    %><td><b> 
>                    <%=rsmd.getColumnName(i)%>
>                     </b></td>                 
>               <% }%>
>           </tr>           
>                   <%
>               int i = 1;
>               resultSet1.first();
>               while (!resultSet1.isAfterLast()) {
>                   for (; i != columnCount; i++) {
>                       %>
>                        <tr id="<%resultSet1.getString(i);%>">                         
>                   <td>
>                   <a id="availableDocument" href="#";  onclick=downloadFunction('<%=resultSet1.getString(i)%>')><%=resultSet1.getString(i)%></a>                  
>                   </td>                                                                       
>                   <%  }
>                   if ( i % columnCount == 0)out.println("</tr><tr>");%>                           
>                   <%resultSet1.next();}%> 
>                   </tr>
>           </tbody>
>       </table>
>       <p>&nbsp;</p>
>       <p>&nbsp;</p>
>       <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
>       <h3>Submitted Requests</h3>
>       <table style="height: 21px; float: left;" width="380">
>           <tbody>
>               <tr>
>                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
>                   <td style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
>               </tr>
>           </tbody>
>       </table>
>       <p>&nbsp;</p>
>       <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
>       <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
>       <h3>Received Requests</h3>
>       <table style="height: 21px; float: left;" width="380">
>           <tbody>
>               <tr>
>                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
>                   <td style="width: 20px;">&nbsp;</td>
>               </tr>
>           </tbody>
>       </table>
>       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Document" /> <input
>           type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Request" />
>
>   </form>
> </body>
> </html>`
> ```

Comment: First you should restructure your code. Use of Scriplet tags is not welcomed  warmly this days.

Comment: Why store files in a DB? I'd just store links to files in DB and use http links to access the files from your JSP page (e.g. <a href="http://localhost/files/file1.txt" >File 1</a>). This way, when the user clicks a particular file link, the download should start automatically. Alternatively, create a file from bytes stored in your DB and return just a link to that file (not a byte stream)